# JsonGenerator output subclass using superclass

Tags: jackson, fasterxml

Is there a way to tell to serialise a Child using it's Super class? Ignoring all fields, getters/setters in the child.

Comment: it depends on what setup you have. if you just use Object Mapper, you can always use this: `mapper.writerFor(FooParent.class).writeValueAsString(foo);` You could probably also use Mixin

Answer (score 0):

That's really going to depend on the technology stack you're using.  If you're using something like C#, you can tell the deserializer what type you want the child to be using something like:`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HalLinkDetail>(someString);`  If you're using something like javascript, that doesn't have strong typing, you may have to do some custom implementation.